# Update Allowed Controls in Placeholder

Tags: powershell-extensions

I need to update "Allowed Controls" field of placeholder using Sitecore Powershell. I have used below code -

```
$contentPlaceholder = Get-Item -Path "master:/sitecore/layout/Placeholder Settings/main"
$contentPlaceholder.Editing.BeginEdit()
$contentPlaceholder.Fields["Allowed Controls"].Value = "{ECACE287-B06E-4530-A4F6-B7FC34AA0FB0}"
$contentPlaceholder.Editing.BeginEdit()
```

But it is not working. Please suggest a solution.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP not shared what he has done so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the only thing you are missing here is `Editing.EndEdit()`, I think its a typo in your code -

```
$contentPlaceholder = Get-Item -Path "master:/sitecore/layout/Placeholder Settings/main"
$contentPlaceholder.Editing.BeginEdit()
$contentPlaceholder.Fields["Allowed Controls"].Value = "{ECACE287-B06E-4530-A4F6-B7FC34AA0FB0}"
$contentPlaceholder.Editing.EndEdit()
```

This is will resolve your problem.

Comment: My bad! it was just a typo!